# Dynamic update Icon in SPFX client Web Part

Tags: document-library, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

I am using office ui frabric details list to display documents on spfx client web part [from here.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist#Implementation)
Now, I want to implement check-in/check-out icons to be displayed on spfx client web part dynamically whenever we perform check-in/checkout.

Or, display documents on SPFx Client Web Part with doc icon type and check-in/checkout doc status icons.

Thanks in advance.